# SCRIPT28: Out of stack space

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-11

Getting stack out of space in IE 10,11 when I try encode a array of data to Json and store it into an array

```js
var SelPeriod = Ext.getCmp('SelectedPeriodGrid');

SelPerioddata = [];

var PeriodsSelected = SelPeriod.getStore('MarkettrackDrillDownPeriods').getRange();

for (var i = 0; i < PeriodsSelected.length; i++) {
    SelPerioddata.push(PeriodsSelected[i]);
}
var SelPerioddatajson = [];

SelPerioddatajson = Ext.JSON.encod(SelPerioddata);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using only the record's data, like:

```
SelPerioddata.push(PeriodsSelected[i].data);
```

---

You can also rewrite this like:

```
var selPeriod = Ext.getCmp('SelectedPeriodGrid'),
  periodsSelected = selPeriod.getStore('MarkettrackDrillDownPeriods').getRange(),
  selPerioddatajson = Ext.JSON.encode(periodsSelected.map(function(record) {
    return record.data;
  }));
```

Comment: Thank you..I used                        

   var SelPeriod = Ext.getCmp('SelectedPeriodGrid');
  SelPerioddata = [];
                var PeriodsSelected = SelPeriod.getStore('MarkettrackDrillDownPeriods').getRange();

    Ext.each(PeriodsSelected, function(item) { 
   // add the fields that you want to include 
     var PObj = { 
   Periodcode: item.get('Period_Code') 
     }; 
   SelPerioddata.push(PObj);
    });

   var SelPerioddatajson=Ext.JSON.encode(SelPerioddata);


Out of space was due to nested arrays inside the array of periods data.So obtained just the needed field.